# CSS highlight on focus

Tags: focus, css

I am using border radius on an input field and when I select the field, it gets a border highlight as if there is no border radius i.e. the imaginary rectangle with sharp edges gets highlighted and not the real rounded corners one. Any cues on how to get the rounded rectangle highlighted? The border radius is functioning perfectly but on focus the highlight is not on the rounded corners.

```
<input class="filter" type="text" name = "Test1" value="Test1"> <!--HTML-->
.filter{border-radius:9px;} /*CSS*/
```

Comment: Please share the relevant code.

Comment: something like this?

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/glowing-blue-input-highlights/

Comment: Along with some code, what browsers are you trying this out in?  They may not have full support for border-radius.

Comment: I am using chrome Version 26.0.1410.43 m. Don't think browser is a problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because `outline` doesn't respect (for whatever reason) `border-radius`, to emulate this it's easiest to use `box-shadow`:

```
.filter {
    padding: 0.4em;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 9px;
}
.filter:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #f90; /* or whatever colour you'd prefer */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5psLX/).

Comment: does exactly what I intend. Thanks! Don't have enough reputation to upvote the answer otherwise would've done it :)

Comment: If the answer solves your problem you're more than welcome to accept the answer (clicking on the green check-mark beside the text).

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type=text], textarea {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
 outline: none;
 padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
 margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
 border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
}

input[type=text]:focus, textarea:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
  margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
}
```

This works like a charm. you will get a good effect on focus